# Why does cascaded WMS not work? (Geoserver)

Tags: geoserver, wms, network, proxy

I run a **Geoserver** installment as a service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.
I try to add a **WMS** source but everytime I get timeout-exception.
As I need to use a proxy I edited **wrapper.conf** as follows:

> > # Java Additional Parameters
> >     wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djetty.home=.
> >     wrapper.java.additional.2=-DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%"
> >     wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dhttp.proxySet=true
> >     wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxyS
> >     wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
> >     wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dhttp.proxyUser=myUsername
> >     wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dhttp.proxyPassword=myPW

I restarted the service after my edits but it does still not work.

My System:
Geoserver 2.6.1 (installed as as Service via windows installer)
Java JDK 1.7
Windows Server 2008 R2

Does anyone have any idea why it is still not working?

Comment: It looks like you have followed http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wfs.html and I do not find any error from your side. You should log the web traffic and see if Jetty is now even trying to communicate with the proxy.

Comment: You should also make a test without proxy for making sure that everything is OK with the remote WMS. I know it can be difficult from a company network and they may not recommend you to test with your own laptop at home or through public WLAN.

Comment: try unchecking use http connection pooling on the DataStore page

Comment: Connection Pooling is not activated because there are no credentials needed to retrieve capabilities xml. I am going to try that at home but the URL I provide is definitely correct and gives an capabilities document – I tried another WMS as well, still connection timeout.